# Tomcat downloading script rather than running them

Tags: apache, perl, tomcat7

I'm trying to setup my tomcat to run .pl and .cgi scripts but whenever I access the cgi servlet path, it simply downloads the script.

I know that with old versions, one had to rename two .JAR files, but I don't think it's necessary with Tomcat 7...

Here's my configuration

---

**OS**:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-027.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Jul 9 15:20:47 EDT 2015
```

---

**${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/web.xml**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cgi-bin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

**${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/context.xml**:

```
<Context privileged="true">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

---

**Script directories**:

```
${CATALINA_HOME}/ROOT/WEB-INF/cgi/test.pl

${CATALINA_HOME}/webapp1/WEB-INF/cgi/test.pl
```

*note*: both of which are set as **0775**

---

**Contents of ${CATALINA_HOME}/Lib**

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   15979 May  7 13:17 annotations-api.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   54466 May  7 13:17 catalina-ant.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  130554 May  7 13:17 catalina-ha.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1621907 May  7 13:17 catalina.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  259519 May  7 13:17 catalina-tribes.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2310271 May  7 13:17 ecj-4.4.2.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   55535 May  7 13:17 el-api.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  124750 May  7 13:17 jasper-el.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  598396 May  7 13:17 jasper.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   87805 May  7 13:17 jsp-api.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  198014 May  7 13:17 servlet-api.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  210978 May  7 13:17 tomcat7-websocket.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    6143 May  7 13:17 tomcat-api.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  786806 May  7 13:17 tomcat-coyote.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  234043 May  7 13:17 tomcat-dbcp.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   71864 May  7 13:17 tomcat-i18n-es.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   43793 May  7 13:17 tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   47036 May  7 13:17 tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  125623 May  7 13:17 tomcat-jdbc.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   31948 May  7 13:17 tomcat-util.jar
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   36271 May  7 13:17 websocket-api.jar
```

---

I am also running Apache in front of tomcat. Here is the virtualhost:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias staging.website.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/tomcat.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/tomcat.log combined

    <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

---

What am I doing wrong? Going by all the tutorials I've gone through, it should work.

**NOTE: when I access the perl script directly through tomcat's port(:8080) I get a blank page rather than a download.**

Comment: Try what happens if your cgi is a binary executeable. I ran into the same issue yesterday with lighty. If the binary exe is run rather than downloaded, you have either a permission problem (does not seem so, as you have 775) or you need to tell the cgi module which handler to use for your script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Tomcat configuration, but, based on having run many Apache servers over the years, my immediate thought is that you may not have enabled script execution for `cgi-bin` at that level:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /filesystem/path/to/cgi-bin/directory
```

Note that [ScriptAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) must be set in the main apache config or your virtual host config.  It won't work in a `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is the perl executable in the OS path, so it can be found by the tomcat process?
2. I am not sure but the CGI and SSI servlet extensions had to be renamed at one time to have them available. Maybe that is the missing step you are looking for?

Comment: **1.** `echo $PATH` outputs:
`/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/native/bin`
perl is in /usr/bin/
**2.** That's what I thought at first, but I don't think it's necessary for tomcat7. I can't see them in `${CATALINA_HOME}/Lib` (contents shown above)

Comment: **concerning 2.** According to the documentation:
The CGI servlet is now included in catalina.jar, so no renaming is
needed in Tomcat 6. (or above)